# How can I customise the text output in a verbatimTextOuput function within a Shiny interactive plot in R

Tags: r, shiny

I want to change the text output to show specific information about the plot point being hovered over such as name and value and such, but I cant seem to workout how to alter the VerbatimTextOutput and what it currently show is not of much use for a quick glace of information. This is the code I am using:

```

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
fluidRow(

  column(width = 8, class = "well",
         h4("Brush to select region. Left plot controls right plot"),
         fluidRow(
           column(width = 12,
                  plotOutput("plot2", height = 300,
                             brush = brushOpts(
                               id = "plot2_brush",
                               resetOnNew = TRUE
                             )
                  )
           ),
           column(width = 12,
                  plotOutput("plot3", height = 300, hover = hoverOpts(id = "plot_hover"))
           )
         )
  ),
  column(width = 3,
         verbatimTextOutput("hover_info", placeholder = TRUE)) 
 )  
)


  server <- function(input, output) {
# Linked plots (middle and right)
ranges2 <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)

output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(adj_p_val_df, aes(x = Genes, y = p_value, col = Model))+
    geom_point()+
    theme(legend.position = "none")
})

output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(adj_p_val_df, aes(x = Genes, y = p_value, col = Model))+
    geom_point() +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges2$x, ylim = ranges2$y, expand = FALSE)
})

output$hover_info = renderPrint({
  cat("Gene info:\n")
  str(input$plot_hover)
})
output$placeholder = renderTe

# When a double-click happens, check if there's a brush on the plot.
# If so, zoom to the brush bounds; if not, reset the zoom.
observe({
  brush <- input$plot2_brush
  if (!is.null(brush)) {
    ranges2$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
    ranges2$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)

  } else {
    ranges2$x <- NULL
    ranges2$y <- NULL
  }
})

 }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```